# How can I make it so only 1 "if-statement" is used if 2 are in the action

Tags: objective-c, uitextfield, alertview

In a game...
When the "done" button is pressed, there are 2 'if-statements': one brings you to the next level and the other returns you home. How can I make it so only one happens at a time? The way it works now, is both the winning and losing 'alertviews' pop up no matter if the user got it right or wrong. This is how it looks:

```
-(IBAction)done {

    if ([entry.text isEqualToString:sentance.text]) {

        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] 
                             initWithTitle:@"Cleared!" 
                             message:@""
                             delegate:nil 
                             cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" 
                             otherButtonTitles: nil];
        [alert show];
        [alert release];

        seconds.text = @"5 Seconds";
    }

    if ([entry.text isEqualToString:entry.text]) {

        NSString *nssScore= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Final Score: \n %i Points", Score];

        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                             initWithTitle:@"Nope! Wrong"
                             message:nssScore
                             delegate:nil
                             cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok"
                             otherButtonTitles: nil];
        [alert show];
        [alert release];
    }
}
```

Comment: Depending on how may `if's` you have left, you could either say `else if ([entry.text isEqualToString:entry.text])` or just instead of the second if type `else` and delete the whole statement

Comment: If you're having trouble formatting a couple of conditionals, I think you should really look into reading a book about the basics of programming. If you really want to dig into Objective-C specifically, I'd recommend you read [Cocoa and Objective-C: Up and Running](http://www.amazon.com/Cocoa-Objective-C-Up-Running-ebook/dp/B0043EWUCU/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1370104091&sr=8-1&keywords=up+and+running+cocoa).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use else if condition.

Like this :

```
-(IBAction)done {

    if ([entry.text isEqualToString:sentance.text]) {

        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] 
                              initWithTitle:@"Cleared!" 
                              message:@""
                              delegate:nil 
                              cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" 
                              otherButtonTitles: nil];
        [alert show];
        [alert release];

        seconds.text = @"5 Seconds";
    }
    else if ([entry.text isEqualToString:entry.text]) {

        NSString *nssScore= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Final Score: \n %i Points", Score];

        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                              initWithTitle:@"Nope! Wrong"
                              message:nssScore
                              delegate:nil
                              cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok"
                              otherButtonTitles: nil];
        [alert show];
        [alert release];
    }
}
```

or you can add a line of code in each block "return;"

like this:

Answer (score 3):

There is something wrong with your second `if`.

```
if ([entry.text isEqualToString:entry.text]) {
```

This if is always true, since why should `entry.text` not be equal to itself?

Also if you have two `if` statements and only one shall be true, you always use a `else if` for the second one:

```
if (<condition>) {

} else if (<other condition>) {

}
```

If `condition` is true, the other `if` is not executed, even if `other condition` is also true. However, in your case your second `if` seems nonsense to me. An `if` that is always true is useless and be left out completely. The code is equivalent to

```
if (<condition>) {

} else {

}
```

Comment: So is there anything I can write that basically says the first 'If' means you got it correct, and the second 'If' is anything except the correct answer..?

Comment: Yes, "if - else if" does exactly that. If the first if is true, the second if is not even looked at. But again, what are you trying to test in your second if? The second if is always true, as it tests a value with itself.

Answer (score -1):

I got the answer guys...

```
    if ([a.text isEqualToString:b.text] == FALSE) {

condition

}
```

Thanks!

Comment: or `if (![a.text isEqualToString:b.text])` is a shorter way of writing that